# Add an answer column to a timeSeries in R

Tags: r, math, time-series

After creating simple timeSeries object...

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(18), ncol = 3)
colnames(data) <- LETTERS[1:3]
charvec <- paste("2009-0", 1:6, "-01", sep = "")
s <- timeSeries(data, charvec)
```

And, adding two columns together, What is the best code to include it as an additional column "D" in the timeSeries "s"?

```
<- s[,"B"] + s[,"C"]
```

Comment: `cbind` maybe?  This is not reproducible. `timeSeries` is not a function in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should had told us that you're using a specific package (by including in your answer `library(timeSeries)`).

You can look at the structure of your object, with `str(s)`, which will tell you that this is a matrix. So, do `x <- s[,"B"] + s[,"C"]` and then `cbind(s, x)` will work. If you need, you can rename the last column.